# How to turn this into an override?

Tags: java, overriding, equals

How do you make something into an override? My book offers a basic explanation but does not show how to implement it into your code and the internet is just as helpful. My directions say to...

Create a Java class called Rational:
...
 that overrides equals such that if the parameter’s numerator and denominator are exactly equal to the current objects numerator and denominator the method returns true, and false otherwise.

I thought I had figured out how to do the override method but was upon further investigation it looks like I messed it up.

```
Rational.Equals(Rational x){
    if(x.numerator == a && x.denominator == b)
    {
      return true;
    }
    else
    {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Any tips or good reading on how to make this into an override method?

Comment: [Inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)

Comment: It looks like you tried to invent your own syntax.  Compilers usually have trouble figuring that out.  Follow the link Sotirios gave you and then look for the subsection on overriding.  Also, what are `a` and `b`?

Answer (score 0):

Briefly, a method *overrides* another when a subclass provides its own implementation of a method with the same signature (return type, name and parameter types) as a super class, eg:

```
class SuperClass {
    void someMethod() {
        // some impl
    }
}

class SubClass extends SuperClass {
    @Override // @Override annotation not necessary, but good practice
    void someMethod() {
        // some overriding impl
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Classes have methods, and when a class extends another class (every single class extends `Object` class) it can declare a method with the same signature as the one in the superclass, so it is called an override. I think you are expected to write something like:

```
class Rational {
  int numerator, denominator;

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof Rational) {
      Rational rational = (Rational) o;
      return numerator == rational.numerator && denominator == rational.numerator;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```